# What are some good sources elasticsearch data download?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, download

Currently I am learning elastic search. Wonder where can I find some good sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go , https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos , this site also has other sample data that you can use to index and play with